# Slideshow, displaying image caption (and then animate it)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to display animated image captions from a slideshow created with a wordpress plugin, meteor slides.

I copied the following function into my functions.php file:

```
function the_post_thumbnail_caption() {
     global $post;

     $thumbnail_id    = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
     $thumbnail_image = get_posts(array('p' => $thumbnail_id, 'post_type' => 'attachment'));

     if ($thumbnail_image && isset($thumbnail_image[0])) {
         echo '<span>'.$thumbnail_image[0]->post_excerpt.'</span>';
     }
}
```

Unfortunately the function doesn't seem to get triggered. You can see what I'm talking about here on my testing website: http://mywptestsite.is-great.org/lalala/

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks
Kim

Comment: Are you talking about this working slideshow of yours? :) I don't get it which part of your page doesn't work. :)

Comment: The problem is that captions are not displayed on the slideshow. I'm trying first to have them displayed with the function above but I'm missing something here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution: [CLICK :)](http://www.billerickson.net/wordpress-featured-image-captions/)

```
<?php

/**
 * Display Post Image and Caption
 *
 * @link http://www.billerickson.net/wordpress-featured-image-captions/
 * @author Bill Erickson
 *
 */
function be_display_image_and_caption() {
    echo '<div class="featured-image">';
    the_post_thumbnail();
    echo '<span class="caption">' . get_post( get_post_thumbnail_id() )->post_excerpt .     '</span>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```